# Oracle - Two records with the same dates aren't equal

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two records with identical dates in Oracle, but when I try to include them in a query with a `date BETWEEN sysdate AND date - 7` in the `where` clause, only 1 of the records are being returned, when both seemingly should meet the criteria as both of them are the same.

Why could this be? And is there any method to put on the field to ensure they are precise?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @doodlebob , please show us your data that is giving you a problem. Put them in your question. Also, show us the code you use . Thanks!

Comment: Probably because DATE values have a time element? In particular `sysdate` does - whatever the time is now when you invoke it.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle dates always have a time component -- alas, though, you don't necessarily see it.

I suspect that you want dates within the past seven calendar days.  That would be something like this:

```
where date >= trunc(sysdate - 7)
```

Your code doesn't really make sense with `date` as one of the `between` limits to `between`.